# Identity quirk with string split()

Tags: python, string, split, primitive

```
>>> 'hi'.split()[0] is 'hi'
    True    
>>> 'hi there'.split()[0] is 'hi'
    False
>>> 'hi there again'.split()[0] is 'hi'
    False
```

My hypothesis:

The first line has only one element in split, while the other two have more than one element.  I believe that while Python primitives like `str` are stored in memory by value within a function, there will be separate allocations across functions to simplify memory management.  I think `split()` is one of those functions, and it usually allocates new strings. But it also handles the edge case of input that does not need any splitting (such as `'hi'`), where the original string reference is simply returned.  Is my explanation correct?

Comment: no and the reason is that the 'is' means the same memory location it is not the same as '==' change your compares to == and they will work fine, the 'is' should only be used to compare elements that are in static memory like None an True / False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe that while Python primitives like str are stored in memory by value within a function, there will be separate allocations across functions to simplify memory management.

Python's object allocation doesn't work anything like that. There isn't a real concept of "primitives", and aside from a few things the bytecode compiler does to merge constants, it doesn't matter whether two objects are created in the same function or different functions.

There isn't really a better answer to this than to point to the source, so [here it is](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/stringlib/split.h#l53):

```
Py_LOCAL_INLINE(PyObject *)
STRINGLIB(split_whitespace)(PyObject* str_obj,
                           const STRINGLIB_CHAR* str, Py_ssize_t str_len,
                           Py_ssize_t maxcount)
{
    ...
#ifndef STRINGLIB_MUTABLE
        if (j == 0 && i == str_len && STRINGLIB_CHECK_EXACT(str_obj)) {
            /* No whitespace in str_obj, so just use it as list[0] */
            Py_INCREF(str_obj);
            PyList_SET_ITEM(list, 0, (PyObject *)str_obj);
            count++;
            break;
        }
```

If it doesn't find any whitespace to split on, it just reuses the original string object in the returned list. It's just a quirk of how this function was written, and you can't depend on it working that way in other Python versions or nonstandard Python implementations.

Comment: that is a great answer - but the real point of all of this should be to point out the obvious - DON'T USE 'is' to compare strings - use '=='

Comment: @gkusner: Looks to me like the questioner already understands that. The question specifically asks about the object allocation strategy, and it doesn't mention any expectation that `x is y` should be true for equal strings `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

So like I said in comment:

```
'hi there again'.split()[0] == 'hi'

>>True
```

Actually your question kind of nailed it - it's an identity.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question about `split()`, why one element will have the same memory location but more than one element will not.  Is it because each function has their own primitive allocations?

Comment: essentially yes the string area is hashed to keep duplication down so the string Hi is stored only once

Answer (score 0):

All data in Python is stored by reference.  (A `PyObject*` in the C implementation)  What you discovered is that `.split()` simply returned `self` as an optimization when the delimiter was not found.  When the delimiter is found it must create separate string objects for each part and so they are separate objects.

*(Unlike Java which has distinctly different data types for "primitives" and "reference/class types" and behaves differently with them)*

Comment: Hmm, I'm learning Java currently and didn't know this; that's interesting. Good explanation.